# Call method of subclass class by instance of superclass

Tags: swift

I have 1 abstract class "A" and some inherited classes AA, AB ... etc. It will be about 15 inherited classes at all.

Variable "point" is an object of one of inherited classes, but I don't know which one, so in the beginning I define it as "A".

Here is a code:

```
import Foundation

class A {

    func callA() {}
}

var point:A

class AA:A {

    func callAA() -> String { return "AA" }
}

class AB:A {

    func callAB() -> String { return "AB" }
}
```

Now "point" is "AB" instance and I want to call method of "AB" class, but it produce the error: `Value of type 'A' has no member 'callAB'`

```
point = AB()   // Correct
point.callAB() // Error
```

How can I call "callAB" method in this case?

I don't want to:

- Define "callAB" method in class "A" and override it in class "AB" because some of inherited classes of class "A" must not contain this method.
- Write something like this:

  ```
  if point is AB {

      (point as! AB).callAB()
  }
  ```

  because there are a lot of inherited classes and I'll have to check any one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional downcast + optional chaining like this:

```
(point as? AB)?.callAB()
```

If point is not an instance of `AB`, nothing will happen

If you need to do call different methods depending on point's type, you can also use `switch` like this:

```
switch point {
  case let aa as AA: aa.callAA()
  case let ab as AB: ab.callAB()
  default: break
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid checking each class, but it seems to me now it's inevitable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call by explicit conversion only.

```
if let pointab = point as? AB {
    pointab.callAB()
}else if let pointaa = point as? AA {
    pointaa.callAA()
}else{
    // something other
}
```